# Excel add IFERROR to formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I can't seem to figure out where I should add `IFERROR` to my formula to prevent returning #N/A when `VLOOKUP` does not find the intended value in the lookup column. Please can someone show me where to add it?

Here is my formula (ps it's horrible so if there's a better way of writing my formula please feel free to comment too!)

```
=IF(
  VLOOKUP(CR$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B7&"'!A1:ZZ1000"),CR$2,0)="",
  "",
  IF(
    VLOOKUP(CR$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B7&"'!A1:ZZ1000"),CR$2,0)="§",
    "",
    IF(
      VLOOKUP(CR$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B7&"'!A1:ZZ1000"),2,0)="§",
      "",
      VLOOKUP(CR$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B7&"'!A1:ZZ1000"),CR$2,0)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: `where I should add IFERROR` - apparently around the innermost `VLOOKUP`, which is the one at the bottom currently?

Comment: Thanks @GSerg, so it will look like this?

=IF(
  VLOOKUP(CR$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B7&"'!A1:ZZ1000"),CR$2,0)="",
  "",
  IF(
    VLOOKUP(CR$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B7&"'!A1:ZZ1000"),CR$2,0)="§",
    "",
    IF(
      VLOOKUP(CR$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B7&"'!A1:ZZ1000"),2,0)="§",
      "",
      IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CR$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B7&"'!A1:ZZ1000"),CR$2,0),"",VLOOKUP(CR$1,INDIRECT("'"&$B7&"'!A1:ZZ1000"),CR$2,0))
    )
  )
)

Comment: You did not put it around the innermost `VLOOKUP`, which is the one at the bottom. You also used `ISERROR` instead of `IFERROR`.

Comment: I had another go using IFERROR and made sure to encapsulate the last VLOOKUP. It told me I had too few arguments for the function. Maybe I need to go back to some tutorials!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem, but I think I'd asked the wrong question, I should have been using the ISERROR function not IFERROR

=IF(
    ISERROR(
        VLOOKUP(
            CR$1,
            INDIRECT(
                "'" & $B7 & "'!A1:ZZ1000"
            ),
            CR$2,
            0
        )
    ),
    "",
    IF(
        VLOOKUP(
            CR$1,
            INDIRECT(
                "'" & $B7 & "'!A1:ZZ1000"
            ),
            CR$2,
            0
        ) = "",
        "",
        IF(
            VLOOKUP(
                CR$1,
                INDIRECT(
                    "'" & $B7 & "'!A1:ZZ1000"
                ),
                CR$2,
                0
            ) = "§",
            "",
            IF(
                VLOOKUP(
                    CR$1,
                    INDIRECT(
                        "'" & $B7 & "'!A1:ZZ1000"
                    ),
                    2,
                    0
                ) = "§",
                "",
                VLOOKUP(
                    CR$1,
                    INDIRECT(
                        "'" & $B7 & "'!A1:ZZ1000"
                    ),
                    CR$2,
                    0
                )
            )
        )
    )
)